# powershell replace text with

Tags: variables, powershell, text, replace

Im still fairly new to powershell and i'm still trying to learn.

Here is my issue im working with:

I have a bunch of bat files which i need to replace with a certain text.
Only Catch is that there is one  thing in the text which needs to be replaced with a variable.

Let me illustrate:

Printer1.bat
Printer2.bat

text that need to be written:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    ::Identify OS
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do set ver=%%a
    set Version=
    for %%a in (95=95 98=98 ME=ME NT=NT 2000=2000 5.1.=XP 5.2.=2003 6.0.=Vista 6.1.=7 6.2.=8)  
do        (

if "!Version!" equ "this" (
  set Version=Windows %%a
) else if "!ver: %%a=!" neq "%ver%" (
          set Version=this
        )
    )

    if "!Version!" equ "Windows XP" (

    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n\\printserver\$printername
    call P:\Script\wait.cmd 1
    sc stop spooler
    call P:\Script\wait.cmd 4
    sc start spooler
    call P:\Script\wait.cmd 1

    ) else echo Scriptet skal ikke kjøres på Windows7

    Ping –n 5 –w 1 127.0.0.1>null


    "@
```

If you notice the variable $printername which is actually the same name as the files name.
So what i want is to overwrite the file with the text but replace the variable with the filename (without .bat)

Not sure if you understand what im trying to do.

i know how to get only the filename without .bat by doing split-path and replace with ""

Ive tried so many Methods like foreach statements. .do while.. nothing i do is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to get the filename, without the path or file extension, you can use the `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method for this. So something like the following would do the trick:

```
$batfiles = ls *.bat

foreach ($file in $batfiles)
{
    $printername = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.Name) 
    $newFileContents = @"
    [... script content removed for brevity ...]

    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n\\printserver\$printername

    [... script content removed for brevity ...]
"@
    $newFileContents | Set-Content $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: `System.IO.FileInfo`-objects includes a `BaseName` property that you can use instead of `system.io.path`. Ex: `$printername = $file.BaseName`

Comment: The `BaseName` property is only available if you get the FileInfo object using `Get-ChildItem` (which `ls` is an alias for) since it's a scriptproperty added by the cmdlet. If you get the file list in another way, e.g. from any of the `System.IO` types, or if you only have strings with the filenames you can't use `BaseName`, but you can use `[System.IO.Path]`. Good suggestion though, since `BaseName` makes for shorter code as long as you get the `FileInfo` object using `Get-ChildItem`.